# Is wrapping the httpClient considered to be a good practice?

Tags: angular, httpclient, angular-http-interceptors

I would like to know what is the best practical solution to handle http errors. In the company that I worked we used to wrap all the httpClient verbs with out own functions and we were able to deal with errors, add token headers from those wrappers.

I know that all these could be done using interceptors so my question is: are you using only interceptors and making the calls using the httpClient from your services or are you combining the two methods and still wrapping all the http verbs?

Example of simple Get call wrapping:

```
  get<T>(api: string, headers?: HttpHeaders, params?: HttpParams): Observable<T> {
    return this.httpClient.get<T>(api, {headers, params}).pipe(
       catchError(error => {
       console.log(error.message);
       return throwError(error);
       }));
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

An abstraction is usually a good idea when you don't want the consumers to know anything about the API they consume so when you will replace the API, the consumer won't care and won't be affected.

In this case, I can think of a scenario where maybe your team will replace the `httpClient` code with some **AngularFire** code let's say, like the following:

```
  get<T>(collection: string, headers?: HttpHeaders, params?: HttpParams): Observable<T> {
    return afs.collection(collection)<T>.valueChanges().pipe(
       catchError(error => {
       console.log(error.message);
       return throwError(error);
       }));
   }
```

FYI (and also not so important), afs represents `AngularFireService`.

`import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/firestore';`

As a result we have changed the inner implementation but the consumers were not affected.

This is an example for a good practice of abstraction. Not the best, but an ok one.

So to be more specific with your question, the error handling here was not important for us but just the abstraction itself.

The error handling did not play a real part in this.

Therefore, it is not considered a best practice to abstract some piece of code just for adding this auto error handling.

A middleware (Interceptor) would be a better approach where you isolate the error handling for every request and do not interfere with the **How** you get or mess with the data (separation of concerns).

Also, for example, it will be very easy to add a `retry` error handling technique (globally) and not in all CRUD APIs you write (simply duplication).

If you need some granularity in certain APIs then there are known patterns to solve this problem in an efficient and readable manner, rather then your team convention.